# How can I pipe variables to sed?

Tags: linux, sed

How can i make the output of echo become the replacement text for 'sed'? I do not understand why i cannot use $p like this.

```
while read p; do
  sleep 1
  echo $p | sudo sed -i '/AuthUser/s/= .*/= $p/' /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
done <emailaddresses.txt
```

Comment: Use double quotes. Also echo $p is not required

Comment: Only: `sudo sed -i "/AuthUser/s/= .*/= $p/" /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`